# Как у парсера на php указать GEO метку, чтоб спарсить товары нужного города?

Tags: php, парсер

Хочу спарсить товары с сайта, на котором есть выбор города, возможно настроить User-Agent у парсера, чтоб мой парсинг заходя на сайт парсил товары нужного города?
все далю на php, заранее спасибо

Comment: Какой парсер используете, покажите код реализации, с какого сайта ?

Comment: Обычно для авто-выбора города используется GEO-IP. Можно попробовать добавить в заголовок ip адрес нужного города